# Missing data when trying to import large columns using powershell

Tags: sql-server-2012, powershell

Powershell command (whitespace added for readability):

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance "$db" -Database "$dbname" -Username "xxxx" -Password "xxx"
              -Query "select logmessages from log
                      where TIME_STAMP BETWEEN '2019-01-11 09:00:00' and '2019-01-11 09:02:00'
                      AND logmessages like '%string%'
                      order by TIME_STAMP"
              -QueryTimeout 0 -ConnectionTimeout 0
| Export-Csv "C:\Users\xxxxx\Desktop\PS\data.csv" -Append
```

Each row result is expected to be around 01 mb. The problem is I'm seeing partial data.

The table has 17 columns and I'm trying to fetch data from one of the column (type:varchar; length: -1) which typically stores xml data close to the size of 1mb per record. When I run a select statement against that column, only partial data is returned.

Comment: what do you mean by partial data? Can you put more info? table structure, example of data, expected results and actual results? We can then help you understand what's going on.

Comment: Hi John, the table has 17 columns and I'm trying to fetch data from one of the column (type:varchar; length: -1) which typically stores xml data close to the size of 1mb per record. When I run a select statement against that column, only partial data is returned.

Comment: It seems to me that an XML column in a .csv file is a problem waiting to happen. Have you looked at the .CSV file to confirm that the data being put in it is both what you'd expect, and formatted as you'd expect?

Comment: The xml data is getting written but its just that the data is incomplete.

Answer (score 2):

The column you are having trouble with us a `varchar(Max)` column. This is one of several "LOB data types", which can be up to 2GB.

The `invoke-sqlcmd` PowerShell cmdlet will, by default, truncate strings to 4000 characters. This can be very useful to prevent accidently pulling back many GB of data from a query without realizing it. This is similar to the default query timeout, which prevents accidental long-running queries.

A "surprise" LOB column containing 2GB per row could pull back 1TB of data in as few as 500 rows--which would have unintended performance issues for other users on the server and possibly even on the local network, assuming a low bandwidth network.

To override that default, simply provide the `-MaxCharLength` parameter to indicate you want more than 4000 characters from your `varchar(Max)` column. (Similar to the way you already supply the `-QueryTimeout 0` parameter.